# Crowd-sourcing a computers/programming related poll through meta? Chat?

Tags: discussion, meta, chat

I'm a college student (no, I haven't posted any homework questions), and I'm currently researching a paper on the health effects of a computer science career.  One of the methods I'm taking is polling coworkers, friends (or strangers) anonymously on their computer usage habits and their health.

I'm wondering if this is something that I could post to SO Meta.  Or maybe just a link in chat?  (But which chat...) Or maybe just not a good fit for this site at all -- if that's the case, I'll be cool with that as well.

Comment: definately not acceptable for meta.  I *think* it could be acceptable in chat, but as I do not frequent chat much at all, I'll hold off recommending it

Comment: related: [Are research survey questions expected to be handled with close votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/278250/165773) and [Can I post a survey for my masters thesis on stack exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247230/165773)

Comment: [Definitely not](http://www.d-e-f-i-n-i-t-e-l-y.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click on `close` below any question and pick off-topic you'll see:

> This question does not appear to seek input and discussion from the
>   community. If you have encountered a problem on one of our sites,
>   please describe it in detail. See also: [What is "meta"? How does it
>   work](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)?

So... when only you post such survey to [meta], you'll receive even more down votes and immediate close.

Comment: Yeah, I figured, but just wanted to double check.  Do you think it would be welcome in chat?

Comment: Each room has it's own rules. You should spend some time there and then judge whether they'll accept such survey.

Comment: @Cullub most larger chatrooms have a set of rules defined there itself or a link to page listing the rules of the room.